# Sort by varchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, sql-server-2014, varchar

In ms sql database table files_master I have a column named 'AstNum' `varchar(100)` it contain data like:
`1/1980 
2/1980
11/1980`
And so on when I sort the column:

```
SELECT AstNum FROM Files_master ORDER BY AstNum ASC
```

It shows me the records `1/1980,11/1980` in the column. `/1980` is the year before slash is increment number please help me how to sort the records I want in result
`1/1980
2/1980
3/1980`

Comment: is that data always like this? or it can be with more / ? E.G. 1/1980/11. and what dbms are you using?

Comment: It works absolutely as intended. Standard strings sorting considers `11` as less than `2` and so on. If you need, say `2/1980` to be outputted before `11/1980` probably it is better to split this field into two and sort accordingly. Also spltting the column looks like a better idea from database design point of view since it leads to more normalized data. Currently your field values looks like you're combining month and year into one single string column.

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server 2014 and the data is always like this `1/1980, 3000/1980` etc

Comment: @ Andy they are not months and `/1980` is only a value and `1, 3, 4, 5` are the increment numbers

Comment: What if there's `2/1980` and `1/1981`? Do you need to sort by year first? Otherwise try `ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(AstNum, '/', '.') AS DEC(10,4))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Select AstNum from Files_master Order by convert(datetime,'1/'+AstNum,101) ASC
```

EDIT : Based on the comments, here is another solution

```
Select AstNum from Files_master 
Order by 
parsename(replace(AstNum,'/','.'),2)*1 ASC,parsename(replace(AstNum,'/','.'),1)*1 ASC
```

Comment: plz chek the comments

Comment: DO not forget to tell: NO INDICES USED.

Answer (score 2):

This will easily not work that way, and probably also violates [standard database rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Your way to go would be to have two columns, both of type `int`, with one of them being the index and the other the year. Say, you have columns `id` and `year`, your request would then be

```
   SELECT `id`, `year` FROM Files_master ORDER BY `id` ASC, `year` ASC
```

Note that the order in which you list the columns in your `ORDER BY` statement depends on primary and secondary order column, so maybe you first want to order by year.

If you **really, really, have to** use this format, and only then, you could probably find a way to use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to split your string, and then have something like (untested):

```
    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`AstNum`, '/', 1) AS `id`, 
           SUBSTRING_INDEX(`AstNum`, '/', -1) AS `year` 
    ORDER BY `id` ASC,`year` ASC
```

Note that this will probably be quite slow to evaluate.

---

Edit: In reply to the comment, since it turns out SQL Server is being used instead of MySQL (what I assumed at the time of writing) the command has to be slightly different, more complex (still untested, offsets might be.. off):

```
    SELECT SUBSTRING(AstNum, 1, LEN(AstNum)-5) AS id, 
           SUBSTRING(AstNum, LEN(AstNum)-3, 4) AS year 
    ORDER BY id ASC, year ASC
```

Comment: Note that SQL Server is used. (Back-ticks and SUBSTRING_INDEX...?)

Comment: @jarlh: At the time I wrote the answer that was not (yet) clear. However, I updated my answer (although a different one was accepted) so it should work with MS SQL Server, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to sort by year first -

```
SELECT AstNum
FROM Files_master
ORDER BY Cast(substring(AstNum, charindex('/', AstNum)+1, 4) as int) ASC,
         Cast(substring(AstNum, 1, charindex('/', AstNum)-1) as int) ASC
```

If you need to sort by only increment number wise then-

```
SELECT AstNum
FROM Files_master
ORDER BY Cast(substring(AstNum, 1, charindex('/', AstNum)-1) as int) ASC
```